# There are a subset or constraint of HTML5 that can be perfectly mapped into XHTML5, and vice-versa?

Tags: xml, html, mapping, polyglot-markup

I need to represent content in a *lingua franca*, that is, in nowadays, the **HTML5** standard — my objective is not to show a page in the web-browser.  I need to represent **only content**, no interface, no layout, no logic (no Javascript).

As remembered in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1415394/287948) (or [programmers questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/272619/84349)), and [the W3C HTML5's Recommendation, "HTML vs XHTML" section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml),

> the DOM, the HTML syntax, and the XHTML syntax cannot all represent the same content.

Ok, but ~90% can be the same (!), and, if I not need Javascript, Styles, etc. and I can enforce some constraints, it will be 100%... So, the question is about **what constraints I need to use (?)** to ensure that all HTML5 serialized as XHTML5 will be represent the same thing, and vice-versa (an XSLT that will back with the original HTML5 document).

There are a  *"subset of HTML5 elemements"*  or a  *"subset with some aditional constraints"*  that ensures the [reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics)) of XHTML5/HTML5 convertions?

Comment: See a [complementar question here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17189/12499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Polyglot Markup: A robust profile of the HTML5 vocabulary**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/), which is currently a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html-polyglot-20140717/), defines rules for a document

> […] that is a stream of bytes that parses into identical document trees (with some exceptions, as noted in the [Introduction](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html-polyglot-20140717/#introduction)) when processed either as HTML or when processed as XML.

You can find the rules for writing such a document in [section 4: *Writing HTML documents*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html-polyglot-20140717/#writing).

Comment: hum... there are a W3C text, ok... But W3C is contradictory (!): or "HTML syntax, and the XHTML syntax *CANNOT* all represent the same content" or "*CAN*" (?). PS: practice shows (any one see that) that CANNOT.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I think the HTML5 Rec means it like "… unless you voluntarily follow some constraints". But note that even polygot markup has ["notable exceptions"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html-polyglot-20140717/#principles), e.g., different DOMs are  created for some `xml`/ `xmlns`/`xlink` attributes.

Comment: "I will voluntarily follow some constraints"... and, sorry! Only now I am reading more the links, understanding that "poliglot markap" is a radical solution for my problem... It is a third representation (!). If I use Poliglot  representation, all conversions (Poliglot-to-XHTML5, XHTML-to-Poliglot, Poliglot-to-HTML5, HTML5-to-Poliglot)  will be reversible (!).  So, if I represent my contents with Poliglot, the converted XHTML5 is reversible for HTML5.  Well it is my conclusion, do you confirm?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I’m not sure I exactly understand your case, so I don’t know if this explanation helps: The *HTML5* specification defines two syntaxes, the HTML syntax and the XHTML syntax. If you follow the rules from the [polyglot markup profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/), you get *one* HTML5 document that conforms to *both* syntaxes (so this document is a valid HTML document *and* a well-formed XML document), and on top that, no matter if your document gets processed as XML or as HTML, it results in (almost) identical DOMs.

Comment: Thanks!  (the old title of the Recommendation summarizes "[HTML-Compatible XHTML Documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-polyglot-20110405/)").